# BigQuery takes too long to load data from Android

Tags: android, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

BigQuery query call takes too long to load data. It takes around 7-8 seconds to get the result the same result takes 1 second on BigQuery Google Cloud Platform.

I have tried the same as per the document for google cloud BigQuery library.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries

```
InputStream is = 
mContext.getAssets().open("service_account.json");
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
.setProjectId("uniorder-prod")
.setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(is))
.build().getService();

QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = 
QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder("standard sql query")
.setUseLegacySql(false)
.build();

JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
Job queryJob = bigquery
                    .create(JobInfo
                            .newBuilder(queryConfig)
                            .setJobId(jobId).build());
queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();

if (queryJob == null) {
throw new RuntimeException("Job no longer exists");
} else if (queryJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
throw new 
RuntimeException(queryJob.getStatus().getError().toString());
}

QueryResponse response = bigquery.getQueryResults(jobId);
TableResult result = queryJob.getQueryResults();

//Current query execution time is 7-8 second
//Expected query execution time is 1 or less than 1 second

//My SQL BigQuery
SELECT
  EXTRACT(DATE
  FROM
    TIMESTAMP(param2.value.string_value)) AS date,
  SUM(param3.value.double_value) AS total_price
FROM
  `uniorder-prod.analytics_200255431.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param1,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param2,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param3
WHERE
  event_name = "total_consumption_res"
  AND param1.key = "user_id"
  AND param1.value.int_value = 118
  AND param2.key = "timestamp"
  AND param3.key = "total_price"
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190601'
  AND '20190630'
GROUP BY
  date
ORDER BY
  date ASC
```

Comment: Running a query on BigQuery (`queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();`) is different to pulling the results of that query back over the wire and into your application (`QueryResponse response = bigquery.getQueryResults(jobId);`). You're first running the query and then fetching the results.

Comment: So what is the solution to reduce the query load time?

Comment: by removing these two lines the result time get reduced but still, it takes 3-5 sec to load the data it should be 1 or below 1 sec.

Comment: Why should it be _"1 second or below"_ i.e. what are you basing this on?

Comment: with high-speed internet connectivity, with this query how much average time it should take to fetch the result from bigquery?

Comment: Hey, @GrahamPolley Can you please help me on this to reduce query response time or I have to use some third party library?

Comment: Your network/internet speed has no bearing on the performance of your query in BigQuery. BigQuery is a multi-tenanted architecture and you share the compute resources with other users. If you want low latency responses, you're using the wrong tool. I'd consider something like CloudSQL or Datastore instead.

Comment: Hi @GrahamPolley great job providing the answer. Can you post your comments as an actual answer for better visibility for another users?

Answer (score 0):

Running a query on BigQuery

`queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();`

is different to pulling the results of that query back over the wire and into your application

`QueryResponse response = bigquery.getQueryResults(jobId);`

You're first running the query and then fetching the results.

You can reduce query time, by removing above lines.

Your network/internet speed has no bearing on the performance of your query in BigQuery. BigQuery is a multi-tenanted architecture and you share compute resources with other users. If you want low latency responses, you're using the wrong tool. I'd consider something like CloudSQL or Datastore instead.